# Comparing 2D boolean arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a problem where I need to compare 1 particular array to hundreds of thousands of others and return a list of results showing how similar they are to each other, I read up that numpy was probably the best library to go about working with arrays (if there's anything better please let me know:) so I scribbled this, but it's still slow. I am not the best at programming so any help to improve this would be immensely appreciated!

```
import numpy as np

list_of_arrays = [np.random.randint(0, 2, (30, 30)) for array in range(100000)]
base_array = np.random.randint(0, 2, (30, 30))
results = []

for array in list_of_arrays:
    results.append(np.sum(np.equal(base_array, array)))
```

Comment: The comparison part is pretty fast, it takes a few seconds because generating all those random numbers take time

Comment: @Giedrius please check my answer below. I've verified that it produces identical results to your code, and it's probably somewhat faster because it uses pure numpy (no loops).  If it's not fast enough for you, you should give up, because it's can't get faster ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of efficient tricks for doing this in numpy. None of them require explicit loops or appending to a list.

First, make the list into an array:

```
list_of_arrays = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100000, 30, 30), dtype=bool)
```

Notice how much simpler (and faster) that is. Now make a boolean base:

```
base_array = np.random.randint(0, 2, (30, 30), dtype=bool)
```

The simplest comparison makes direct use of broadcasting:

```
results = (base_array == list_of_arrays).sum((1, 2))
```

The equality of two booleans can also be obtained from their XOR:

```
results = (~base_array ^ list_of_arrays).sum((1, 2))
```

Running `~` on `base_array` is much faster than doing it on `list_of_arrays` or the result of the XOR and has the same logical effect.

You can simplify the sum by raveling the last dimensions:

```
results = (base_array.ravel() == list_of_arrays.reshape(100000, -1)).sum(-1)
```

Comment: Wow, that's way better, thank you very much !

Comment: @GiedriusGurevičius. Which one did you end up going with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy broadcasting magic to do it in one list without list comprehension or loops of any kind:

```
results = np.equal(base_array, list_of_arrays).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

You have so many arrays that it can't get much faster ;)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I guess I'll need more RGBs

Comment: Yeah, machine power is the best you can do at this point. Was it any faster?

Comment: from 1.7 to 1.46. Still faster, thanks mate !

Comment: Well, better than nothing! :)

Comment: Try using bitwise xor